# how to export large numbers from HeidiSQL to csv

Tags: export-to-csv, heidisql

I use HeidiSQL to manage my database. 
When I export grid row to CSV format file, the large number `89610185002145111111` become `8.96102E+19`

How can I keep the number without science notation conversion?

[image]

Comment: If you open the csv file with Excel, have you tried to change the format of the cells?

Answer (score 0):

HeidiSQL does not do such a conversion. I tried to reproduce but I get the unformatted number:

```
id;name
89610185002145111111;hey
```

Using a text editor, by the way. If you use Excel, you may have to format the cell in a different format.